# JQtouch useFastTouch dont work on iPhone with Phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova, jqtouch

Or does it? JQtouch has, as default, useFastTouch set as true. But my app still has the 300ms delay, actauly its up to one secound.  Then i read that i should use ".tap event"  but how do i attache the tap event to all my a-tags ? i tryed alot, but then i loose the animation between pages or the delay is still present.

I found this thread, wich is 8 month old... Still no solution?: https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/issues/360

When i try to use this solution, (scroll down to testing the webapp...) but my app crasches:
http://www.dconnell.co.uk/blog/index.php/2011/08/01/developing-an-iphone-app-using-html-css-javascript-and-phonegap-from-concept-to-app-store/

Answer (score 0):

I sort of made a solution. First of all i had to remove all animations from JQtouch. Which really speeded things up... 
To get rid of ghost clicks i made a style which disable the pointer

```
<style type="text/css">
        .pointer-events-none {
            pointer-events: none;
        }
    </style>
```

Then in my Functions i placed this code:

```
$('a[href=#some_class], a[href=#some_class]').not('a.on').bind('touchstart', function(e) {

               var pageToGoTo = $(this).attr('href');
                   jQT.goTo(pageToGoTo, 'slide');

                   $('.scroll').addClass('pointer-events-none');

                   setTimeout(function(){
                      $('.scroll').removeClass('pointer-events-none');
                   }, 1500);

  });
```

It works, but if I set the timeout lower 1500 the app crashes...